# Why is my Parallel QuickSort method slower than the sequential method?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, invoke, quicksort

I am new to parallel programming and I am unsure why the `QuickSortParallel` method is slower than my sequential version (Without the Parallel.Invoke). I have a jagged array that consists of a hundred thousand 9 digit numbers that I pass to be sorted. Unfortunately, when I use the `QuickSortParallel` method it ends up being almost 5 times slower than the sequential version.

Could I do more than just using Parallel.Invoke on the data source?

```
    public static void QuickSort_Parallel<T>(T[] array2) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        QuickSortParallel(array2, 0, array2.Length - 1);
    }

    private static void QuickSortParallel<T>(T[] array2, int left, int right)
        where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        if (left >= right)
        {
            return;
        }

        SwapElements(array2, left, (left + right) / 2); //median pivot
        int last = left;
        for (int current = left + 1; current <= right; ++current)
        {
            //CompareTo, compares current array index value with
            if (array2[current].CompareTo(array2[left]) < 0)
            {
                ++last;
                SwapElements(array2, last, current);
            }
        }

        SwapElements(array2, left, last);
        //Recursive
        //Executes each of the provided actions in parallel.
        Parallel.Invoke(
            () => QuickSortParallel(array2, left, last - 1),
            () => QuickSortParallel(array2, last + 1, right)
        );
    }

    static void SwapElements<T>(T[] array2, int i, int j)
    {
        T temp = array2[i];
        array2[i] = array2[j];
        array2[j] = temp;
    }
```

Comment: What are you actual timings like? Are we talking milliseconds or seconds? (I'm hoping ms for just 100K elements.)

Comment: Sequential 1.4sec, Parallel 5.8sec

Comment: What about checking recursive depth and going sequencial (calling `QuickSortParallel()` sequencially) after it exceed a certain thresold (ex : greater than the `NumberOfPhysicalCPU * someconstant` )  ?

Answer (score 2):

More than likely, you're problems are coming from overhead with the threads.

Using threads normally makes CPU intensive work faster, however starting a new thread involves substantial overhead, and if you're giving too many threads too little work, then you can make your program run slower.

When you run the following line:

```
    Parallel.Invoke(
        () => QuickSortParallel(array2, left, last - 1),
        () => QuickSortParallel(array2, last + 1, right)
    );
```

...you are possibly causing the current thread to spawn two more threads (depending on how `Parallel.Invoke` is implemented). If my mental math is correct (and if `Parallel.Invoke` does indeed create new threads), you're creating `n * log(n)` threads--an enormous number!

If you want to see performance gains, you need to balance the # of threads--more is not always better. A good way to limit the number of threads by using the system thread pool:

```
System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
        () => QuickSortParallel(array2, left, last - 1));
System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
        () => QuickSortParallel(array2, last + 1, right));
```

...or something along those lines. You could also implement your own threading pool, if you feel inclined to do so.
a

Another option is to limit the depth of recursion, thus limiting the number of threads.

Comment: No; `Parallel.Invoke` uses the threadpool.  (as well as the calling thread, I think)

Answer (score 2):

All those recursive invokes are killing you. This article http://reedcopsey.com/2010/02/26/parallelism-in-net-part-11-divide-and-conquer-via-parallel-invoke/ is very relevant.

Comment: Yep. Makes no sense to fire up a whole new thread to sort a sequence of three elements. Must balance between forking and sorting the subsequence on the current thread.

Answer (score 0):

Contention surrounding the use of the SwapElements method? Try dropping the logic of the SwapElements method right into your method/loop, rather than calling out to it...this will allow it to be a part of what happens on each parallell thread that is spawned, rather than being a potential bottleneck. See if that get's you anything...just a suggestion though, not sure if it will prove useful.